# I am trying to write a DAO interface using Datastax 4.2.2, but getting several compile errors

Tags: java, gradle, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have the following POJO:

```
@Table(name = "order", readConsistency = "QUORUM", writeConsistency = "QUORUM")
public class Order {    
    
    @Column(name = "id")
    @PartitionKey
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private String customerId;

    @Column(name = "loyalty_id")
    private String loyaltyId;

    @Column(name = "customer_email")
    private String customerEmail;

    public Order() {

    }
    ... getters and setters
}
```

And now I am writing the OrderDao as following:

```
    import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.*;

    @Dao
    public interface OrderDao {
            @Select
            Order findById(String orderId);

            @Insert
            void save(Order order);

            @Delete
            void delete(Order order);
    }
```

And when I do `./gradlew build` I get the following errors:

```
error: Invalid return type: Select methods must return one of [ENTITY, OPTIONAL_ENTITY, FUTURE_OF_ENTITY, FUTURE_OF_OPTIONAL_ENTITY, PAGING_ITERABLE, FUTURE_OF_ASYNC_PAGING_ITERABLE]
    Order findById(String orderId);
```

```
error: Insert methods must take the entity to insert as the first parameter
    void save(Order order);
         ^
```

```
error: Missing entity class: Delete methods that do not operate on an entity instance must have an 'entityClass' argument
    void delete(Order order);
         ^
```

I am implementing by following the documentation here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.2/manual/mapper/ . What could be the possible cause of this?

Thanks.

Comment: also, please upgrade to the latest driver - there were many fixes since 4.2.2... Plus, new driver is "unified", working with both DSE & Cassandra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `@Entity` annotation on your `Order` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order", readConsistency = "QUORUM", writeConsistency = "QUORUM")
public class Order {
```

Comment: I just found out that I used `@Table` instead of `@Entity` by mistake. Thanks though :)

Comment: But I am now getting the following:
`com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.MapperException: Entity Order does not declare a primary key` at the following :  `CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder().build();`
`OrderMapper mapper = new OrderMapperBuilder(session).build();`
`orderDao = mapper.orderDao(CqlIdentifier.fromCql("order"));`

Comment: @AnirbanAcharya It would be best to ask this as a new question, as it doesn't appear to be related.  More people will see it and you'll be more likely to get a thorough answer.